# Groupie RecyclerView Expand Parent's Layout To Include Children

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview, groupie

I've a expandable recyclerView made using Groupie which I would like to have the children included on the parent's same layout to make use of the borders for its card view. Not sure how to achieve that though.

Instead of

[image]

I would like to have this

[image]

This is the top of my parent's layout

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cv_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
```

(Tried with wrap content as well but couldn't see much difference)

And this is the layout for their children

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: @Francisaliny :-  Is achieve?

Comment: Hi, I moved on to your other project after this post but dont remember having being able to fix it.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar with groupie recycleview. I think its must have feature which the library is lacking.